# ADFS 2.0 Sharepoint Event ID 364 error

Tags: sharepoint, adfs

I'm attempting to configure a Sharepoint server to communicate with ADFS for authentication.  I am following the instructions found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235(v=office15).aspx

When I attempt to open the web page, I recieve an ADFS error.  It shows up as an Event ID 364 and gives the following log.

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Exception details: 
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'ASP.homerealmdiscovery_aspx'. ---> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HomeRealmDiscovery.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.homerealmdiscovery_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(IHttpHandler handler, Boolean preserveForm)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveContext.TransferToASPX(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean preserveViewState)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Dispatchers.ClaimsProviderUserInterfaceDispatcher.DispatchInternal(SignInContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(PassiveContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HomeRealmDiscovery.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.homerealmdiscovery_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at HomeRealmDiscovery.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

- The Identifier claim for the logged in user is not blank in active directory. For e.g. during configuration PS commands if you set EmailAddress to be the identifier claim, then all users logging in to Sharepoint must have Email adrress associated with them
- Logon token expiration should not be 0. Check this at your ADFS server. Below command can be used to Set token lifetime
  `Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName “SharePoint 2013” -TokenLifetime 30`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm fairly new to all of this.  How would I check to see if the user is black in active directory?

Also how do I run the command for the second set of ideas you presented?  Both Powershell and Command Prompt are saying "Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust" is not recognized.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you explain the first item in more detail?  As far as I can tell, every use must have an e-mail-address before they can connect.

I tried the second command, but there doesn't appear to be a difference.

Comment: You're right, every user must have an email address.

Comment: The second command has to be run on ADFS server. The error log seems to be from ADFS server.
Could you please share output of Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust from ADFS server and the output of get-sptrustedsecuritytokenissuer from sharepoint server